# Netty SocketIO - Cannot assign requested address in AWS

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, socket.io, netty-socketio

I have implemented a websocket server using Spring framework and Netty SocketIO. While development I used the host address as `localhost` and the server was working perfectly fine.

When I'm trying to deploy my code to AWS, I changed the host address to my instance's public IP address. But I'm getting the following error and I'm unable to start my server

```
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Can't assign requested address
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannel.doBind(NioServerSocketChannel.java:125)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.bind(AbstractChannel.java:484)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1080)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeBind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:430)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.bind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:415)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:903)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.bind(AbstractChannel.java:197)
at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap$2.run(AbstractBootstrap.java:350)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:380)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:357)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:116)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:137)
```

If I can's assign my public IP address in AWS for host then which IP address can I use to start my Socket server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check your /etc/hosts file. 127.0.0.1 or 192.168.10.10 or whatever your IP is that is pointed to **localhost** must point towards your website also.

```
127.0.0.1 localhost my.website.com
```

Now, start your socket with **my.website.com** as host and choose a port as you wish.

Comment: @DaniAkash Can you please provide steps to access the netty socket-io server from AWS?